# How do I upgrade from Java 1.8.0 to Java 11?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using the latest 2020 version of `Eclipse`. After installing JRE from https://www.java.com/en/download/windows-64bit.jsp, when I run Eclipse, I get this error:

```
Version 1.8.0_261 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 11 or greater is required.
```

After checking out `java -version` from command line, I've found out that my Java version is **1.8.0_261**.

So, do I have to upgrade to Java 11? If yes, then how?

Comment: @Abhishek https://adoptopenjdk.net is what you're looking for. Free, legal, supported long-term, endorsed and used by many people, projects, and companies. Nothing oracle offers for java11 is all of: Free, licensed, and supported.

Answer (score 4):

Download AdoptedOpenJDK 11 (which is free popular legal JDK to use) from here : https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Install it and set `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME` in the environment variable. That's all.

But you can use JDK from other free vendors as well.

Comment: probably not, the thing you linked to is not legal* to use except for very limited purposes. Just.. follow your own link and read it. Oracle __DOES NOT PROVIDE__ any build of JDK11 unless you either pay or agree to a very onerous license. The only one they provide is the latest (so, right now, JDK15). I suggest you send people to e.g. adoptopenjdk.org.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Then, it's the choice of the user. Yeah !! AdoptedOpenJDK or Corretto can be a good choice.

Comment: Also, *How to update Java*, or *How to install* is sort of off-topic when it comes to programming.. besides, answers can vary, depending on OS, Java version, approach of the installation one takes (installer, msi, binaries zip, etc.) and so on.

Comment: @AnishB The choice to install known broken, unsupported, or unlicensed stuff? That's.. not much of a choice. And in some particularly backwards jurisdictions, illegal. Stop recommending this. There are free, supported, java11 versions out there. For example, adoptopenjdk or coretto.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Ok !! I'm editing my answer to add for corretto or AdoptedOpenJDK

Comment: @AnishB. please do not do that. It is, as I have already explained, very broad, and depends very much on the case. Besides, *how to install* software is not really a programming problem. If I were you, I would have deleted this answer.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri all you explained is how the question is overly broad. Which is on its face ridiculous, no? "I have this error, how do I fix it" is quite specific. That the answer requires half a book's worth of history and licensing terms, okay, well, that sucks, but that doesn't retroactively make the question 'overly broad'. This shouldn't have been closed.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I'm not sure I clearly get what you mean, but even in the case of *I have this problem and how to update Java* is broad and seems to me off-topic. Doesn't it depend on several parameters of the environment? I'm also not sure I understood what is *ridiculous*. I have explained why this is off and broad. Should I have gone into every possible permutation of the configurations why is this broad?

Comment: Well, I'm not downvoting neither the question, nor the answer, here. All I'm saying, is that, even if the question is "How to install Java 11 Build4423.x.y.z.t.z", with a specific build version, it is still broad and off-topic, as it depends on many other points, like (for instance) OS, installation way (binaries, installer, etc.) and other possibly quite important/valid aspects.